# How not to include null values in min

Tags: c#, datagridview, min

I have a DataGridView in my form that has many columns. In four of those columns, I want to get the lowest value using Min(). However, often times at there are columns that has null values. I don't want null included when it tries to compare the four values.

The problem is that if one of the columns is null, it will always return null when I want it to return the lowest value. Any ideas?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_csv.Rows)
{
    mfn_new[i] = row.Cells[21].Value.ToString();
    mfn_used[i] = row.Cells[22].Value.ToString();
    fba_new[i] = row.Cells[23].Value.ToString();
    fba_used[i] = row.Cells[24].Value.ToString();

    var list = new[] { mfn_new[i], mfn_used[i], fba_new[i], fba_used[i] };
    string min = list.Min();
    MessageBox.Show(min);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: *The problem is that if one of the columns is null, it will always return null when I want it to return the lowest value* Are you sure. I think it returns null only if **all** values are null. Are you mixing null with empty string?

Comment: for instance, `var test = new [] { "5", null, "3", "8", null }.Min();` returns "3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.Where(item => item != null).Min()
```

But why are you representing your numbers as `string`? I assume you are looking for `Min` of numbers, not of a string - consider changing the type

Also the following line `mfn_new[i] = row.Cells[21].Value.ToString();` might throw a `NullReferenceException` in the case that the `.Value` is `null` so checking later on if it is `null` isn't relevant.

---

**After you updated the question id suggest:**

```
mfn_new[i] = row.Cells[21].Value?.ToString();
....

list.Where(item => item != string.Empty).Min()
```

Comment: I'm getting to that point in using int. where'd you get 'item' though? I tried this:

`string min = list.Select(item => item != null).Min();`

It's saying an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'. My apologies, I'm a beginner programmer

Comment: it is the input parameter of the predicate. [Check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. You solved a problem I was trying to solve for the past 2 hours :)

Comment: did I do it right? I tick the check mark right down the up/down vote buttons

Comment: @Bjorn - Yes :) the up/down voting is to day is this a good/useful answer (can be for several answers per question) and then the marking with the V can be only for one answer per question

Comment: I've already ticked the check! Just one more question. I tried assigning the column values to an int array.`mfn_new[i] = row.Cells[21].Value.ToString();` I understand that this won't work because it tries to convert the value to ToString I guess? What's the right way to do it? I declared this `int[] mfn_new = new int[dgv_csv.Rows.Count];` prior